# Template Template Arguments Inconsistent with Deduced Template Arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The following code fails to compile with the error `template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<template<typename, typename> class Blah, typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
void print_tuploid(const Blah<KeyType, ValueType>& tup) {
    std::cout << "first value: " << std::get<0>(tup) << " second value: " << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto stuff = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
  print_tuploid(stuff);
}
```

The original intention behind this code is irrelevant, at this point I'm just trying to understand why this is considered to be invalid.

If I change the call to `std::make_tuple` into `std::make_pair`, the code compiles and runs correctly, which leads me to believe there's something weird going on that's specific to `std::tuple`.

I was originally thinking that `std::tuple` might have some extra, defaulted, template arguments I wasn't aware of, because if I change the definition of `print_tuploid` to the following, the code DOES compile for both `std::make_tuple` and `std::make_pair`:

```
template<template<typename...> class Blah, typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
void print_tuploid(const Blah<KeyType, ValueType>& tup) {
    std::cout << "first value: " << std::get<0>(tup) << " second value: " << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
}
```

But when I tried to dump out the deduced type of `stuff` using the following code:

```
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
class TypePrinter;

int main() {
  auto stuff = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
  TypePrinter<decltype(stuff)> error;
}
```

It reported: `implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TypePrinter<std::__1::tuple<int, int> >'`, leading me to believe this is not the case.

Also, as a side question, why does reference collapsing not occur in this context? The following code is also considered invalid:

```
#include <iostream>

template<template<typename, typename> class Blah, typename KeyType, typename ValueType>
void print_tuploid(Blah<KeyType, ValueType>&& tup) {
    std::cout << "first value: " << std::get<0>(tup) << " second value: " << std::get<1>(tup) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  auto stuff = std::make_pair(1, 2);
  print_tuploid(stuff);
}
```

Giving the error: `no known conversion from 'std::__1::pair<int, int>' to 'pair<int, int> &&' for 1st argument`.

Basically I'm just trying to extend my template knowledge by understanding what exactly is going on here. Sorry for the long post, and thanks in advance for any guidance anyone is able to provide.

Comment: Can't expand to a full post right now, but matching exact template parameters to parameter packs is considered incorrect. There's a paper but I forget if it was accepted into 17.

Comment: Reference collapsing occurs for a parameter like `T&&` - it's an lvalue reference if `T` is deduced to be lvalue reference, and rvalue reference otherwise. `Blah<KeyType, ValueType>` can't possibly get deduced to be an lvalue reference type - it's clearly a class type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue with the function is that it matches against a template class that takes exactly 2 arguments. In reality, `std::tuple` has the template signature of `template <typename...>`. The distinction lies in that `tuple` takes an arbitrary amount of template parameters, while your function expects 2.

`std::pair` works fine because the template signature is `template <typename, typename>` which matches exactly.

There is a proposal, although I am not able to find the latest version, that enables this sort of specialization. It seems to have passed into C++17, or at least something similar to it, as the cppreference page for template template parameters considers this a valid example. The proposal I found is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html).

The reason why your second version does not accept `std::pair` is because it expects an rvalue reference. Once you have a (partially) specialized type, you cannot treat `&&` as a forwarding reference.